Do you know this generational starship story? I can't remember the title or author
I believe this was a short story/novella in a collection (anthology) by various authors, probably published in the 1960s or 1970s (Golden Age). It is about a generational starship where rebellion is brewing because the ship has been going so long and many on board would like to stop and settle, or even return to Earth. The captaincy has become hereditary but the heir apparent is at odds with the ship's goal and is trying to use the lower-class rebels to seize power for himself. He has some kind of inter-dimensional transportation device that allows him to move between places in time/space instantly, so he can escape dangerous situations. However, the rebels have noticed that he always puts his hand in his pocket just before he vanishes and they plan to kill him and grab it. However, as they shoot him, he presses the trigger and ends up between dimensions. "And there he hung, as dead as a man would ever be". - ending?

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Have you asked this already? It's very similar to a question asked earlier but with some details changed. If you are the same user, you may need to merge your accounts so you can edit info into the original question

Not me, but my son asking the same question.

Thank you for clarifying!
